# Context-menu search doesn't work for Bing

Tags: dns, bing, internet-explorer-11

In IE11, when I select text, right-click and choose **Search with Bing**, I always wind up at my ISPs DNS search page.

Hovering over **Search with Bing** (or any link) shows the URL down below:
[image: Search with Bing Tooltip]

- URL IE is using: http://www.bing.com/search?q=Elizabeth+Southerns+&form=IE8SRC&src=IE-SearchBox
- Where I wind up: http://www.dnsrsearch.com/search.php?search=Elizabeth+Southerns+&src=10

I get redirected to the ISP's page even if I enter this address in Chrome. If I remove the `&form=IE8SRC&src=IE-SearchBox` it works though.

I've tried removing Bing as a search provider and added Google, which works fine. I changed it back to Bing search, and now the problem is back.

Here are my search provider settings: [image: Search Provider Settings]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to opt out of this "feature" at:

http://www.dnsrsearch.com/prefs.php

Comment: Weird. After opting out, everything works now. And Bing's context-menu icon magically reappeared, too. Thanks!